# Find all primes $p$ for which the equation $x^6 \equiv -1$ mod $p$ has a solution.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure if i could apply Wilson's theorem here.

Answer (score 1):

The case $p = 2$ being trivial, assume $p > 2$.

If there is a solution $x$, then $-1 \equiv (x^{3})^{2} \pmod{p}$ is a square, so $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Conversely, assume $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. So there is $a$ such that $a^{2} \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$.

Now if $3 \mid p - 1$, there is an element of period $12$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^{\star}$, and this will do as an $x$. If $3 \nmid p - 1$, then $z \mapsto z^{3}$ is a bijection on $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}^{\star}$, so an $x$ such that $x^{3} = a$ will fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(x^3)^2 + 1^2 = 0$ mod $p$, $p$ is $1$ mod $4$ (Fermat's two squares)

$(x^2)^3 + 1^3 = (x^2 + 1)(x^4 + x^2 + 1) = 0 $ mod $p$

$\implies p | x^2 + 1$ as $p$ has to be of the form $a^2 + b^2$ (Fermat and skipping steps)

So if we take any $p$ such $p$ is a factor of $x^2 + 1$ then the equation $x^6 + 1 = 0$ mod $p$ holds.